# How to limit the operation for applying PATCH in jsonschema?

Tags: python-3.x, jsonschema, patch

Currently, we have have a patch endpoint for jsonschema and now we want to limit the operation that we can do while applying the patch.

The patch endpoint looks like this:

```
def patch(self, name, version):
  ...
  schema = Schema.get(name, version)
  serialized_schema = schema.patch_serialize()
  ...
  data = request.get_json()
  
  patched_schema = apply_patch(serialized_schema, data)
  serialized_data, errors = update_schema_serializer.load(
                patched_schema, partial=True)
  ...
```

data example:

```
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/config/notifications/", "value": "foo" },
  { "op": "add", "path": "/config/", "value": {} },
  { "op": "remove", "path": "/config/notifications/"}
]
```

Here we want to only have `add`, `remove` and `replace` operation. Is there any way to only apply patch for these operation and not for `copy`, `move` and `test`?

Answer (score 0):

In your schema definition, define op as an enum with only the options that you want